# Displaying name issue in WEB MATRIX?

Tags: webmatrix

I would like to display first name of the user, once member login. i.e, webmatrix WebSecurity.CurrentUserName to first name

Also, i did changed the code, but I can't able to login,

WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnecti…
"UserProfile", "UserId", "FirstName", true

Comment: I would like to help you, as I have done exactly what you're asking more than once, however, your question lacks enough explanation. Did your code store the first name of the user into a table when that user registered? If so, can't you just query that value? If not, can't you set it up to store the first name upon registration?

Answer (score 0):

`WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` creates the database objects based on your parameters. Later Changes to this settings will after the project due to several references made by the helper while creating the Membership schema. Its either you drop the database and then recreate it or you manually edit the table columns, trace all primary key references. Rerun the project again.